# Save erased when updating through iTunes unity game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, save

I recently pushed an update through iTunes for my game. I'm using `Application.persistentDataPath` in Unity to save my game in a file. Everything is fine with Android but on iOs all of my game's save were erased with update. When I was testing with TestFlight it was working fine so I can't understand why it doesn't work now with this update...

Do you have any idea about this?